# Explain behavior of ADD COLUMN xxx varchar(255) DEFAULT FALSE;

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I've faced a strange SQL query like

```
ALTER TABLE some_db.some_table
    ADD COLUMN metadata_labels varchar(255) DEFAULT FALSE;
```

I'd expect it to fail because I'm adding a Boolean default value for the `varchar` column. But at least at Postgres, it is executed successfully and I see the following:

[image: SQL query result]

Looks like some weird type coercion to me

Why this query does not fail due to a type mismatch?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is just an implicit conversion of false to "false", similar as you could also write for example default 200 and this will be converted to "200". Use a boolean column instead if you really want to store false or true only.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've clarified the question. I'd expect the query to fail instead of silently converting the type, and don't understand the logic behind that. It sounds like JS typing caveats to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an assignment cast from `boolean` to `text`, so it must be that `DEFAULT` values are acceptable if there is an assignment cast to the target data type.

Looking at the `adbin` column in the `pg_attrdef` catalog, I can see the the actual default expression that is stored is

```
"varchar"(text(FALSE), 259, FALSE)
```

where the outer function is the conversion to `varchar(255)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not even know about System Catalogs!

Answer (score 4):

Postgres does implicit type conversion. It's documented here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv.html

So your SQL Statement is perfectly valid, as `false::bool` can be perfectly converted into `'bool'::text`.